# Mixed data partitions in phylogeny reconstruction in R

Tags: r, phylogeny

Let's have two matrices, one DNA sequence alignment and one consisting of binary characters.

```
dna <- matrix(c("a", "a", "a", "t", "a", "a", 
                "t", "t", "a", "g", "c", "c"), 
              ncol = 4, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:3], NULL))

bi <- matrix(c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0), 
             ncol = 4, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:3], NULL))
```

We can reconstruct the phylogenetic relationships with the `phangorn` package:

```
library(phangorn)
dnatr <- optim.pml(pml(tree = rtree(3, tip.label = LETTERS[1:3]), 
                       data = phyDat(dna)), 
                   optNni = TRUE)
bitr <- optim.pml(pml(tree = rtree(3, tip.label = LETTERS[1:3]), 
                      data = phyDat(bi, type= "USER", levels = c(0,1))),
                  optNni = TRUE)
```

Function `phangorn::pmlPart` should run partitioned analyses, but it does not combine the phylogenetic information in partitions to reconstruct a single phylogeny.

```
tr = pmlPart(~ edge + nni, object = list(dnatr, bitr))
```

How can I set up a partitioned analysis that uses mixed datatypes (DNA sequences and a binary character)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, the following code should work:

```
tr = pmlPart(edge + nni ~ . , object = list(dnatr, bitr))
```

The documentation on CRAN is unfortunately a bit outdated.
Please make sure you have the latest development version of *phangorn* from  *github* (`remotes::install_github("KlausVigo/phangorn")`) installed.

PS: For tree rearrangements you need at least 4 tips, so with your example will ignore the *nni* term.